# MvvmCross Tabs Controller wrapped into UINavigation Controller?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, mvvmcross

I'm using Xamarin.iOS and MvvmCross 5.x. My root view is Tabs Controller and I want any request to show a child would force a stack navigation outside of the tabs (not inside).

So I defined my root view as below:

```
[MvxFromStoryboard]
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public partial class HomeView : MvxTabBarViewController<HomeViewModel>
```

Unfortunately, the root navigation controller is not a UINavigationController (as I expect based on attribute) but HomeView which essentially tabs view and I'm unable to achieve my goal.

Then I overrode the ios presenter to manually create root UINavigationController:

```
public class MySuperCoolIosViewPresenter : MvxIosViewPresenter
{
    private UINavigationController _rootViewController; 

    public MySuperCoolIosViewPresenter(IMvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetWindowRootViewController(UIViewController controller)
    {
        _rootViewController = new UINavigationController(controller);
        base.SetWindowRootViewController(_rootViewController);
    }

    protected override void ShowChildViewController(UIViewController viewController, MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.Attributes.MvxChildPresentationAttribute attribute, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        _rootViewController.ShowViewController(viewController, _rootViewController);
    }
}
```

But this code fails somewhere deep in the MvvmCross while trying to set the controller `base.SetWindowRootViewController(_rootViewController)` with the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object\n  
at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.Presenters.MvxIosViewPresenter.CloseTabBarViewController () [0x00036] in <861dee92d7924acc93d876339b4b95f9>:0  
at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxTabBarViewController.ViewWillDisappear (System.Boolean animated) [0x0001f] in <861dee92d7924acc93d876339b4b95f9>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr)  
at UIKit.UIWindow.set_RootViewController (UIKit.UIViewController value)
```

How can I achieve my goal without creating an extra ViewModel and View for the Root view (I don't like this approach because in this case Android will freak out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was looking for a solution guys from MvvmCross updated the framework to address exactly the issue to version `5.1.1` (I was using `5.1.0`). Ios presenter logic has been updated honor the `WrapInNavigationController` properly (before in case of tabs it was ignored). Unfortunately the `ShowChildViewController` was failing after that with `InvalidCastException` but I was able to handle this by prioritizing my Root Navigation Controller over Tabs Controller

```
    protected override void ShowChildViewController(UIViewController viewController, MvxChildPresentationAttribute attribute, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (viewController is IMvxSplitViewController)
            throw new MvxException("A SplitViewController cannot be presented as a child. Consider using Root instead");

        if (ModalViewControllers.Any())
        {
            if (ModalViewControllers.LastOrDefault() is UINavigationController modalNavController)
            {
                PushViewControllerIntoStack(modalNavController, viewController, attribute.Animated);
                return;
            }

            throw new MvxException($"Trying to show View type: {viewController.GetType().Name} as child, but there is currently a plain modal view presented!");
        }

        // this logic goes first for the root controller 
        if (MasterNavigationController != null)
        {
            PushViewControllerIntoStack(MasterNavigationController, viewController, attribute.Animated);
            return;
        }

        // then try to show child for the tabs
        if (TabBarViewController != null && TabBarViewController.ShowChildView(viewController))
        {
            return;
        }

        base.ShowChildViewController(viewController, attribute, request);
    }
```

I hope it will save someone's time.

Comment: You should override `ShowChildView` in your TabBarController and return false in case you want a view to be displayed as a child of your MasterNavigationController. Apologies for the lack of documentation on this, will update the site in short :)

Comment: @nmilcoff yep, this approach will work even without a custom presenter, thanks! It’s still unclear why showChildView of TabViewController gives me an invalid cast exception, is it a big of 5.1.1?

Comment: It is indeed a bug, the code should return false instead of breaking. Will fix it now, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3):

I created this sample that contains exactly what you need: https://github.com/rrispoli/SampleTabs

Comment: thank you for your efforts, the app works exactly how I want. Unfortunately, you are using some manual tabs creation logic which is covered by mvvmcross already (and I want to stick to that logic) and custom ios presenter tricks which are not clear to me: 1. why in `ShowRootViewController` you do not call the base class method? 2. Why in the same method do you call `SetWindowRootViewController` instead? 3. Why in `ShowChildViewController` you have to set `TabBarViewController` (basically every time whenever you want to show a child your presenter doing that). Please clarify

Comment: Oh... I opened the original mvvmcross code and got the answer - the code is taken from there :)

Comment: I've test the solution and I'm unable to use it with tab creation via MvvmCross when `IMvxNavigationService` is used to create tabs by a simple call to Navigate<ViewModel> method

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. With this code you don't need to have the viewmodel pre-instantiated, but let the MvvmCross instantiate for you: https://github.com/rrispoli/SampleTabs/blob/master/SampleTabs.iOS/Views/MainView.cs#L47

You just need to change the CreateTabFor signature to accept a Type parameter that represent a viewModelType you need.

Then, you call the method:

CreateTabFor(0, "My tab", null, typeof(ChildViewModel));

Comment: Thank you @RafaeldeAndrade for your great and simple example! It saved my evening :)

Comment: @DominikR I'll update soon the repository code with new version of MvvmCross.